# Malformed Config.xml file

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

This is my config.xml file. While I am trying to create a new version build, phonegap is throwing error but I am not able to find the exact cause in config.xml file. I tried to rename my app and since then I am getting this error. Please help.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id="com.imsosp.uniqueName"
    versionCode="36"
    version="1.0.9">

    <name>App Name</name>
    <description>
            Description
    </description>
    <author email="xxxxx@gmail.com.com">
    All Education Inc.
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <platform name="android">
            <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
            <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        </platform>


    <feature name="SocialSharing">
      <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0" /> <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" /> <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" /> <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" /> <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" /> <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" /> <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" /> <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" /> <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" /> <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" /> <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" /> <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" /> <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="10000" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" /> <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" /> <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />  
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3500" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1.0" />


    <allow-navigation href="http: //*/*" />
    <!-- Plugins -->


    <!-- Core plugins -->

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk" source="npm" />
    <!-- Third party plugins -->
    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />


    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>


    <!--
    Define access to external domains.
    <access /> - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
    <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
    Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->

    <!--
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" /> - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" /> - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->
    <access origin="http://wikipedia.com" />
    <access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="tel://*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="mailto://*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please, post here the error you get

Comment: "malformed config.xml"  this is the error I am getting while building apk on build.phonegap.com.
@RomanHotsiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your quotes in the first line to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. Application name should not contain any special character but in my case I was using "&" thats why I was getting error.